# XMLSerializer skips element values

Tags: javascript, dom, xml-serialization, xmlserializer

I've got some Javascript code which serializes the entire DOM tree as follows:

```
(new XMLSerializer()).serializeToString(document)
```

But what I get is somewhat different than I'd expect. Specifically, I get the HTML source, but not the values of the various input/selects. If objects are inserted into the DOM, I get those objects, but again, no values.

However, if I were to walk through the DOM in Javascript for some other purpose, I would have access to every input's value.

What gives? Obviously, I'm missing some very basic concept, but I've no idea what.

Can I get the full DOM as an HTML/XML formatted string, **with** input/select values? If so, how?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is due to the fact that a DOM form input maintains its `value` *property* (which reflects the current state) separately from its `value` *attribute* (which represents the initial value of the input and is used by `XMLSerializer` to serialize the DOM).

I've written about this several times on Stack Overflow. Here's a recent example: [jQuery .attr('value', 'new_value') not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506937/jquery-attrvalue-new-value-not-working/5507093#5507093)

Comment: Heh. I sincerely wish I'd known the right search terms to find that. In the end, I did in fact have to do `oNode.setAttribute("value", oNode.value);` to get it working correctly.