# Why can't set value of input text by jquery after delete text?

Tags: javascript, jquery

This is my code: i want change value of city when click button

```js
function add()
{
        $("#city").attr("value","abc");
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<input type='text' id='city' value="123"/>
<input type="button" id='btnChange' value="Change" onclick="add();return false;"/>
```

If after Page load , i click button ,it working ok: `city =abc`.

But if after Page Load, i select and delete text "123", i click button , it not working. `city=""`

Why can't set value of input text by jquery after delete text?

Comment: this same https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5506937/jquery-attrvalue-new-value-not-working

Answer (score 2, accepted):

use jquery [val](https://api.jquery.com/val/) instead of `attr`

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type='text' id='city' value="123" />
<input type="button" id='btnChange' value="Change" onclick="add();return false;" />
<script>
  function add() {
    $("#city").val("abc");
  }
</script>
```